# Search by title, abstract and author keywords boolean query

Tags: search, ieee

I try to search a general query in ieee search which is this ("data" AND "social media")

If I use this in the simple general search it works fine. However if I try to use specific criteria in order to search only in title or abstract or author keywords using this boolean query

```
("Publication Title":("data" AND "social media") OR "Abstract":("data" AND "social media") OR "Author Keywords":("data" AND "social media"))
```

I can't take anything. Is there anything I make wrong in the process? How can I search in ieee search?

Answer (score 0):

I applied your query in the IEEE Digital Library and it returned me 17 research paper means your query is completely fine.

You query searches the word 'data' and 'social media' in publication title, Abstract and Author keywords.

There is also advance search in IEEE Xplore Digital Liberary in which you can perform search easily by searching it from either metadata or metadata and fulltext.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem in the IEEE databases. The IEEE search engine seems to be very particular about its syntax. The following syntax worked for me (it gave 6592 results in IEEE Xplore)

```
(("Abstract":"social media") AND ("Abstract":data)) OR (("Publication Title":"social media") AND ("Publication Title":data)) OR (("Author Keywords":"social media" AND "Author Keywords":data))
```